# Flutter-ChatGPT SDK - Continue discussion with context

Tags: flutter, dart, openai-api

I'm currently trying chat_gpt_sdk on Flutter (dart)
https://pub.dev/packages/chat_gpt_sdk

When i start a conversation , api return me a message. but that's all.
I cannot continue to talk, I need to find a way to retrieve history from last responses ans requests.

I Use this code to initialize text

```
final request = CompleteText(
    prompt: "My input message", maxTokens: 100, model: kTranslateModelV3
);
```

Attempt the request with the onCompleteText method

```
final response = await chatGPT!.onCompleteText(request: request);
```

I make some search on few forums and the OpenAI Discord but no reponse
And few stackoverflow posts are posted about this problems but its very recent message without any clear response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution

Get the history from a list of message

```
String history = messages.reversed.map((e) => e.text).join('@');

String history = messages.reversed.map((e) => e.text).join('@');    
final msg = history + lastMessage + "@";
```

And just after I concatenate the history with the last message sent and no forget a stop symbol like @

Comment: This works like a charm? Could you guide on how we can display the history of chats? Like I have saved the 'messages' and also can retrieve it, but how to show it as history like how it is shown in ChatGPT? Could you help on this?